# Create nodes and edges from tree structured object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, algorithm, tree

I have a tree in an array

```
[
  '-',
  [
    '+',
    [
      '*',
      2,
      3
    ],
    4
  ],
  3
]
```

So each level consists of an operator and 2 operands. Each operand can either be the operand itself or another array containing an operator and 2 operands.

I need to draw a graph, so I will have to create the nodes and edges from this tree.

I have made this to work in cytoscape

```
function walk(arr, prevRootNode) {
  var rootNode = cy.add({
    group: 'nodes',
    data: {
      name: arr[0]
    }
  });

  if (prevRootNode) {
    cy.add({
      group: 'edges',
      data: {
        source: prevRootNode.id(),
        target: rootNode.id()
      }
    });
  }

  if (Array.isArray(arr[1])) {
    walk(arr[1], rootNode);
  } else {
    var child1Node = cy.add({
      group: 'nodes',
      data: {
        name: arr[1]
      }
    });

    var child1Edge = cy.add({
      group: 'edges',
      data: {
        source: rootNode.id(),
        target: child1Node.id()
      }
    });
  }

  if (Array.isArray(arr[2])) {
    walk(arr[2], rootNode);
  } else {
    var child2Node = cy.add({
      group: 'nodes',
      data: {
        name: arr[2]
      }
    });

    var child2Edge = cy.add({
      group: 'edges',
      data: {
        source: rootNode.id(),
        target: child2Node.id()
      }
    });
  }
}

walk(ast);
```

but the code is difficult to read and I will rather make the data independent of cytoscape, so I want one array of nodes and one array of edges, and each edge should have two fields `source` and `target` which hold the ids of the nodes which the edge links together.

Comment: Data from first sample and code example contrdiction each other. Could you write actual init data and expected result?

Comment: `Array.isArray`? you have no array in your given data. why check?

Comment: youd data and your try is now not consistent anymore.